# Trying to initiate Function

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to initiate a function when a user clicks on a button.

At the moment it initiates when the site is loaded and when a user scrolls or resizes the browser. But how do I get it to work when a user clicks on a specific button. At the momment the button has a onclick="sort();".

```
var lazy = [];
registerListener('load', setLazy);
registerListener('load', lazyLoad);
registerListener('scroll', lazyLoad);
registerListener('resize', lazyLoad);

document.getElementById('sort').addEventListener('click', function() {

});

function setLazy(){
    lazy = document.getElementById('img-loading').getElementsByTagName('img');
    // console.log('Found ' + lazy.length + ' lazy images');
} 

function lazyLoad(){
    console.log('lazyLoad initiated');
    for(var i=0; i<lazy.length; i++){
        if(isInViewport(lazy[i])){
            if (lazy[i].getAttribute('data-src')){
                lazy[i].src = lazy[i].getAttribute('data-src');
                lazy[i].removeAttribute('data-src');
            }
        }
    }
    cleanLazy();
    console.log('lazyLoad END');
}

function cleanLazy(){
    lazy = Array.prototype.filter.call(lazy, function(l){ return l.getAttribute('data-src');});
}

function isInViewport(el){
    var rect = el.getBoundingClientRect();

    return (
        rect.bottom >= 0 && 
        rect.right >= 0 && 
        rect.top <= (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight) && 
        rect.left <= (window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth)
     );
}

function registerListener(event, func) {
    if (window.addEventListener) {
        window.addEventListener(event, func)
    } else {
        window.attachEvent('on' + event, func)
    }
}
```

Comment: Which function shall be executed by clicking on the button?

Comment: Essentially I need the lazyLoad to initiate, but when doing so the if statement inside of the loop does not work. It works when the page loads, scrolls or resizes though.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var button=document.getElementById('button'),
    clickFunction=function(button){
      alert('click');
    };

button.addEventListener('click',clickFunction);
```

```html
<input id="button" type="button" value="test">
```